# Loading tables in Javascript with pagination and filtering

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, pagination, tablesorter

Currently I'm using jQuery [uitablefilter](https://github.com/gregwebs/jquery-uitablefilter) which is a simple plugin which filters the table rows. that works well.

So now I was looking for implementing pagination since the table could have 1000+ rows. I'm using Twitter bootstrap tables so I would like to maintain the UI. I know table sorter plugin does support pagination but not sure how to implement it.

If I have 1000 rows, do I need to load the rows in the table as html and then hide certain rows to filter or can it be more dynamic and do lazy-loading?

Comment: You could use something like [Tablesorter](http://tablesorter.com/) or [Datatables](http://datatables.net/) to add pagination to your table.